# User Notifications

Tags: emails, notifications

Does anyone have an idea how to send email notification to the user when the file is uploaded?

This file can be uploaded either to the new node or while modifying an existing node.

Comment: Why would a user need an email for a file he uploads himself, or are we talking about really large files here? (You want the mail as a reminder after uploading the file, but before saving the node?)

Comment: You might be able to use Rules for this.

Comment: This cannot be implemented with rules as there is no event for file upload and as for why the user needs the email, this is the spec from the client

Comment: Are you using 7 or 8? please tag your question with the version

Answer (score 1):

I know you mentioned that you can't use Rules, but I think you can.

In your condition, just add your file field and set it to "Data value is empty" and negate it.

Comment: You'd need to go a bit further, but rules could still handle it. Just need to check whether the node is new, and if not, check whether the file id matches the file id from the previous revision before sending the email

Comment: That's a good point. I didn't consider that a file could be replaced with another file when the node is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I did not put the description. The website which is drupal 7 has media module installed. I want the notification to launch whenever a file is uploaded in the media manager before it is attached to a node.